# Android Button click show webView

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

I have a crazy problem. In my `XML`, I have 2 `Buttons`

each `Button` for Facebook and Twiiter

and in the same layout I have a `WebView`

when I click Facebook `Button`,it opens facebook in `WebView`
and same goes for Twitter

this is my layout code:

pages.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="@string/page"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#3600ff" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonFace" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFace"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonTwitter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonTwitter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTwitter"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/twitter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your problem explain clearly....

Comment: So whats your problem?? What do you want to achieve??

Comment: As you can see , in my Xml file 2 Buttons for facebook and Twitter and WebView ok , now i want when I click for anyone buttons show facebook or twiiter website in WebView in same Xml file

Answer (score 0):

Made these changes:

```
private WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

ON Button Click:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
```

I hope it may works.

Comment: do u take permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

this xml code

call this intent

```
 Intent faq =  new Intent(this,WebViewActivity.class);
                faq.putExtra("url", "Your URL");
                faq.putExtra("header_text", "Heading");
                startActivity(faq);
```

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/incld"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </WebView>
```

and this is java code

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private TextView header_maintext;
    private TextView headeroptiontext;
    private RelativeLayout back;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);


         url_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
         header_maintext_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("header_text");

        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        header_maintext= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_maintext);
        header_maintext.setText(header_maintext_string);

        headeroptiontext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headeroptiontext);
        headeroptiontext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

          back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
          back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
                    {
                        webview.goBack();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
             }
        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "tittle", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(url_string);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: do u take permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />